# Discrete Choice Modeling from Aggregate Data

Tags: count-data, discrete-data, choice-modeling

I am working on a problem where customers make choices.

A traditional setting for problem for example would be: Model the  Travel by air, bus, car. Each choice is made based on several variables like cost, wait time, travel duration etc. In this case, the data may look like: [Discrete choice models; estimating probability of new alternatives](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247352/discrete-choice-models-estimating-probability-of-new-alternatives)

The problem I am having is that, I cannot observe individual choices, but only aggregate choice. That is, in one month, I know how many cars, air, bus etc a population sample has chosen. What are the appropriate classical models (on the likes of logit, probit etc) to handle this?

One way I am thinking of is to unwrap the choices into individual choice. That is if I know 7 people chose car, I'd add 7 rows to the dataset with car=TRUE, bus=FALSE, air=FALSE. That seems quite contrived.

Can someone point me to the right direction in this regard, please? I am essentially looking for R packages and papers that I can read. I have a complex Bayesian model to do this, and I am looking for baseline models that have already been explored to compare and contrast against.

Comment: You can check out this similar thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142000/multinomial-logit-with-aggregate-data